# Is there a way to check if a call is a call or a delegatecall?

Tags: solidity, evm, delegatecall

I want to add a modifier to one of my function that checks wether the function call is a call or a delegatecall?
Is there any way to figure that out? May be with some assembly?

Comment: Uniswap v3 does this thing. You can see their implementation: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/NoDelegateCall.sol

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is !It's actually a similar process that deployed libraries are using to ensure that they are not called directly, only through delegate call with some caveats.

What you want is :

- Save your contract's address **into it's code**
- When called, check if `address(this)` equals the value saved before.

You can easily do that with [immutable variables](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=immutable#immutable) :

> The contract creation code generated by the compiler will modify the
> contract’s runtime code before it is returned by replacing all
> references to immutables by the values assigned to the them. This is
> important if you are comparing the runtime code generated by the
> compiler with the one actually stored in the blockchain.

In solidity you could write it that way :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Target {

  address immutable _this;

  constructor() {
    _this = address(this);
  }

  function isDelegate() public returns (bool) {
    if (address(this) == _this) {
      // This is a call address(this) is this contract
      // We are executing in our own context.
    }
    else {
      // This is a delegatecall address(this) is not this contract.
      // We are executing in another contract's context.
    }
  }
}
```

Do not go for alternatives as checking for a specific storage value, as they are 1) more costly and 2) unsafe.

I hope that answers your question.