# Figure out the address used at construction time for a regular smart contract

Tags: evm, bytecode, deployed-bytecode, yul

Is there anyway to figure out what was the address used at construction time and find it in the bytecode?
For example I know that for libraries they are storing it in the contract in order to be able later to compare this stored address to the `address` upcode and revert the transaction if some non pure/view function are directly called (instead of `delegatecall`ed).
Can it be done in a normal contract without having to manually store the contract address?

Comment: No, the way I showed you here (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/128931/84305) is the only practical way. Decompiling a library contract shows that this is exactly what they do to ensure a revert on a direct call. They just have an implicit constructor doing that immutable variable logic. But it's the only practical way for now. You could pre-compute your contract address and hard code it, but that serves the same purpose and is just much less convenient...

Comment: Great thank you hroussille (btw I upvoted you but it doesnt show because I dont have enough reputation)